# parsing json python with subkey

Tags: python, json, parsing

after tring 10 or 12 solutions in stackflow, I can't parse correctly json output from subprocess.
these codes work fine. as you can see, I build 2 lists and try to build a dictionnary with only 2 of thoses values.

```
list_ssl_json = subprocess.check_output('/usr/local/bin/aws iam list-server-certificates', shell=True)
    list=json.loads(list_ssl_json)
    count=0
    while count < len(list['ServerCertificateMetadataList']):
            cns.append(list["ServerCertificateMetadataList"][count]["ServerCertificateName"])
            arns.append(list["ServerCertificateMetadataList"][count]["Arn"])
            count += 1
    count=0
tablist=dict(zip(cns,arns))
```

but, from this json subprocess output, I can not get "SSLCertificateId" value.

```
{
"LoadBalancerDescriptions": [
    {
        "Subnets": [
            "subnet-99dc23fc", 
            "subnet-ec3a02aa"
        ], 
        "CanonicalHostedZoneNameID": "Z3NF1Z3NOM5OY2", 
        "CanonicalHostedZoneName": "ImmaCloudLB-546492219.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com", 
        "ListenerDescriptions": [
            {
                "Listener": {
                    "InstancePort": 80, 
                    "LoadBalancerPort": 80, 
                    "Protocol": "HTTP", 
                    "InstanceProtocol": "HTTP"
                }, 
                "PolicyNames": []
            }, 
            {
                "Listener": {
                    "InstancePort": 443, 
                    "SSLCertificateId": "arn:aws:iam::732791872228:server-certificate/dlyphenix-af.immanens-delivery", 
                    "LoadBalancerPort": 443, 
                    "Protocol": "HTTPS", 
                    "InstanceProtocol": "HTTPS"
                },
```

thanks for your helps

Comment: I don't understand your question - what exactly is the problem?

Comment: don't name your `list` list..................

Comment: The problem is: I'm unable to get "SSLCertificateId" from this json output.

Comment: You have to traverse all the keys til you reach `SSLCertificateId: "LoadBalancerDescriptions", "ListenerDescriptions", "Listener"`, handling each one's content based on it's data type.